# How to show specific fields from json in mule flow

Tags: json, rest, url, mule, mule-component

Hi i am trying to create a simple mule flow where i get the json data from a rest url
eg . 
         {
           "token" : 123,
           "id" : 456,
           "email" : "abc@abc.com",
           "status" : "Success"
          }

now i want my response to show only 2 fields so my final output json would be something like this ..

eg.
     {
        "id" : 456,
        "email" : "abc@abc.com"
     }

I know this is very basic. I would be glad if anyone could help me out since i am very basic to mule.Thanks !

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                <mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
                    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
                http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
                http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
                http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
                    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
                    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="reqres.in" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
                    <flow name="testFlow">
                        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api/users/2" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>

                        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                    </flow>
                </mule>
```

Comment: so where is the code returning json

Comment: @Developerkt i have attached the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in transform message component after http:request component

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
id:payload.id,
email:payload.email
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to mule u can try this simple solution using a simple set payload and some json path expression.

```
<flow name="jsonTransform">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/jsonTransform" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="POST"/>
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;id&quot; : &quot;#[json:id]&quot;, &quot;email&quot; : &quot;#[json:email]&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transform the payload after the HTTP listener to remove those fields.

You can approach this two different ways: Specify what elements *should* be in your payload, or specify what elements *should not* be in your payload.

Anirban's answer specifies what elements should be in the payload. Here's how you specify what elements should not be in the payload:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload - "token" - "status"
```